# Can i add a filter button in ssrs report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, filter, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have an SSRS report which displays lacks of records.
the user wants a filter button on the report to display only filtered records.

I tried searching on the internet for the same but unfortunately, I didn't find anything helpful.
[image: ssis_execution_report]

This screenshot shows the SSIS execution report having a filter button.

Comment: Maybe this helps, because a parameter is like a filter. They get displayed above the report and the user can select values. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54581864/in-ssrs-2008-how-are-parameters-passed-down-to-the-datset-query-or-can-they/54586513#54586513

Comment: @Shahab Haidar - You can use the Parameters for your requirement.

Comment: You could add an extra parameter (called FILTER) to determine if you use the other parameters or not - though normally you would just leave the other parameters blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an option called filter in SSRS reports, you can use parameters to filter data. There are many articles describing the whole process, as example you can refer to the following articles:

- [Creating a multi-option parameter report for SQL Server Reporting Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3484/creating-a-multioption-parameter-report-for-sql-server-reporting-services/)
- [Include Report Parameter Selection Values in Report Output for SQL Server Reporting Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3518/include-report-parameter-selection-values-in-report-output-for-sql-server-reporting-services/)
- [In SSRS 2008, how do pass variables from one report to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496783/in-ssrs-2008-how-do-pass-variables-from-one-report-to-another/54506356#54506356)